# How to position a Cocoa window to minimize overlap with other windows?

Tags: cocoa, nswindow, heuristics, window-managers, nsworkspace

I'm working on a Cocoa app that has a main window and a preview window.  I'd like the preview window to automatically position itself to minimize overlap with other windows — it definitely shouldn't overlap my app's main window, and it should try not to overlap other applications' windows.

How should I do this?

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. Have you tried anything so far? Which part of this are you most unsure about? Getting other windows' positions? An algorithm for determining a rectangle with the least-overlap of other rectangles? Writing Cocoa code to actually position an NSWindow?

Comment: First, I'd like to know whether there's some simple built-in API for doing this.  Failing that, an outline for an algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has a sample application called [Son of Grab](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SonOfGrab/Introduction/Intro.html) that shows you how to consume all current windows.

`CFArrayRef windowList = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly, kCGNullWindowID);` will give you the current windows. You can interrogate the `kCGWindowBounds` value to get the bounds of the returned windows.

Comment: Thanks.  Any thoughts on a least-overlap algorithm?